# Google Drive: obtaining a Credential object

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

The Google Drive documentation describes two authorization modes for using their service.  The first is intended for use by HTML/JavaScript client side applications, and Google provides [sample code here](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/auth/web-client).  I was able to successfully get this code working.  However, for my use case I am building an extension to a Java web application which will make use of *offline* access to Google Drive.  This will require server side authorization.  Google also provided [sample code](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/auth/web-server) for this use case.  One thing is very unclear about the code they provide, and I will draw your attention to the following method:

```
static Drive buildService(Credential credentials) {
    return new Drive.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credentials)
        .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
        .build();
}
```

I cannot figure out how to create a `Credential` object to feed into the `buildService()` method.  I tried deserializing the `StoredCredential` object written by Google's client side sample code, but this cannot be converted to a `Credential` object.

Once I can obtain a `Drive` object, using it is pretty much plain vanilla and is nothing to fear.

I am sure that I am missing something obvious here, and I hope a Google Drive expert can shed some light on this problem.  By the way, I read through a couple dozen questions on Stack Overflow regarding this topic, but many had unaccepted answers, and few seemed relevant to my specific use case.

Comment: Have you tried this quick start?: https://developers.google.com/+/web/samples/java  It is the example of a simple web app that contains all the necesary steps to do the authentication in both server side and client side. Check the 'PeopleServlet' class in the example https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-quickstart-java/blob/master/src/com/google/plus/samples/quickstart/Signin.java